# Validation summary in MVC3, combining predefined and ModelState errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, razor

I'm having problems understanding how to best implement unobtrusive client side validation that works together with errors added in the controller with `ModelState.AddModelError()`.

So, this is the current code:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
```

The error message will correctly appear if I'm leaving out firstname. If I enter a firstname and tab out, the message will disappear - as it should work.

When no client error exists and I can submit this form, I have to do a check against the database that the user doesn't already exists. If it does, I'm adding an error with:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("", "User already exists")
```

<s>When returning the model, an error box is shown, but there is no message in there.</s>

If i change `@Html.ValidationSummary(true)` to `@Html.ValidationSummary(false)` I will see the error message correctly returned with the model. **(Edit: Jan's comment solved this part)**

The problem now is, that all client validation will be duplicated and shown in two different places.

Also, I would like the errors to show up in the same place/div. As it is now, it will be two different validation summaries.

Any way around this?

Comment: This should work (empty string as key parameter to AddModelError and ValSum(true)). Are you surem you pass an empty string as key parameter?

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't compiled after setting it to empty. Now it displays the error message correctly. I still have the problem that there is two error boxes now: One for the summary with the modelstate error and then one for the client errors that are predefined with: @Html.ValidationMessageFor()

Answer (score 0):

The validation you have set next to your text boxes you can set the text of the `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)` to `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "")`.  Or if you wanted to add a '*' if you wanted.  Then you would not have the message next to your textbox.

Comment: Actually I don't have those message next to the text boxes. I have them above everything as a summary. This didn't work, there are still two different error boxes. One displaying the model state error and one displaying the client side errors.